# Giving exception while mapping the simple value type of collection in hibernatre

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an `Entity` called `Person` which has name property as `String` and person `petnames` has collection. When mapping to `Hibernate` I am getting exception.  How can I resolve this problem?

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.myapp.struts;

import java.io.Serializable;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.CollectionTable;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;

/**
 *
 * @author hyva
 */
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPetname(Set<String> petname) {
        this.petname = petname;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    private String name;
    private Set<String> petname;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "petname", joinColumns =
            @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID"))
    public Set<String> getPetname() {
        return petname;
    }
}
```

****Exception:****

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(petname)]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.myapp.struts.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:28)
    at com.myapp.struts.HibernateComplexValue.main(HibernateComplexValue.java:19)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(petname)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:266)
    aJava Result: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `@CollectionTable` over to be an annotation on `getPetname` as shown below:

```
private Set<String> petname;

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "pets", joinColumns =@JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID"))
public Set<String> getPetname(){
      return petname;
}
```

Comment: I am not mapping entity to entity.

Comment: the code you posted seems to be incomplete. Could you post all of it?

Comment: What is the version of your hibernate and what columns does `Person` have?

Comment: Hibernate 3.2.5 I am using.

Comment: What about the `JPA` version?

Comment: Can u just tell me how to check the JPA version plz tell me.

Comment: "File -> Project Structure -> Module -> Dependencies". In the list of jars, you can see the version of the `jpa*.jar` that you have.

Comment: I am using netbeans IDE

Comment: I am using JPA 1.0 jars

Comment: sorry I am using JPA 2.0 jars

Answer (score 0):

<s>Your annotation @CollectionTable is located after your property petName! Is is a copy/paste error?</s>

You have not mapped your petname column. And your default property name is the same as your table name (**petname**)...
What is supposed to be the name of the column holding the pet names in this table?

Try adding `@Column(name="YOUR_COLUMN_NAME")` to force the mapping to this column.

Comment: still I am facing the same problem .